# Google app engine send mail raises ApplicationError: 1 Internal Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Years back I built a simple mail form that has been working like a champ, but in the last couple months the logs show I'm getting an error when EmailMessage's send() method gets called.

I wrote a quick test to see if a stripped down version of an EmailMessage would work without error:

```
class TestEmail(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    fromAddress = "APPOWNEREMAIL@gmail.com"
    email = mail.EmailMessage(sender=fromAddress)
    email.to = self.request.get('to') + '@gmail.com' 
    email.subject = "Test Email"
    email.body = "Testing the email system"
    email.html = "<strong>Testing the <em>email</em> system</strong>"
    email.check_initialized()
    email.send()
```

Simple enough, but if I call that with:

```
http://MYAPPNAME.appspot.com/test-email?to=TOTALLYLEGITEMAIL
```

I still get the same error (note check_initialized() isn't throwing an error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
handler.get(*groups)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappname/3.354527616249361817/myappname.py", line 370, in get
email.send()
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 895, in send
raise e
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 1 Internal error
```

I haven't made any recent changes to the app, it's a lightly used app well below quota, it's sending as the email associated with the app owner and after spending a few hours scrutinizing the code, I'm still no closer to an answer.

Even more distressing, every Google search I come up with offers no new help. The best I could find was this question: [Google app engine send mail service raises exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130882/google-app-engine-send-mail-service-raises-exception) which sounds exactly like my problem, but in that case there wasn't a solution, the problem just went away.

Any idea how I can track this one down? Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: What does line 895 of `/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py` look like?

Comment: "there wasn't a solution, the problem just went away.". That is probably the case here as well. Sometimes GAE has outages.

Comment: That's what I assumed at first, but then I noticed I was getting the error consistently in my logs for a couple months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your appid?

There is currently an issue that sending mail from an application whose appid is the same as the owner's gmail name will fail. eg, I have a gmail address "moishel at gmail dot com"; if I created an app whose appid is 'moishel' (before version 1.6.0) it will fail when trying to send mail. Note that this problem does not exist for apps created with version 1.6.0 or after.

Here's the issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5320

Comment: That would explain that. My appid is franklincountyhumane which does in fact match the gmail address it's trying to send from.

Comment: I just tried sending an email and it worked perfectly this time! What's the correct course of action if someone else runs into this problem? Can they deploy a new version of their app with 1.6.0+ or do they need to get in touch with a Google App Engine team member to make a correction behind the scenes (as indicated in your link)?

Comment: This'll be fixed for all applications by 1.6.1.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I was able to get some emails to send, but looking through past logs this error has still been popping up every few days. Here's what I tried (without any change in behavior): I updated my launcher to 1.6.1 and deployed a new version of the app. I created a new gmail address that doesn't match the appid, made that a developer on the project and set the from address to the new email address. I switched the new address to be the owner and set the old as a dev. Finally, I removed the franklincountyhumane user from the project and still no joy. I'm stumped here with a broken app.